# How to authenticate a daemon to access MS Custom Translator API

Tags: authorization, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-translator

I am setting up a training pipeline for MS Custom Translator data and want to automate the training process. I know that I am suppose to use Azure AD and I have been able to access the Custom Translator API using the OAuth2 OpenId Connect running an API. Then I also tried to use the certificate authentication but I cannot select the Microsoft Custom Translator API it is disabled.
I am able to access other APIs like MS Graph just not MS Custom Translator, is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have just added some sample code demonstrating how to handle some of the common Custom Translator tasks through the API. The sample code can be found here with detailed instructions.

https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/CustomTranslatorApiSamples

Note that Custom Translator uses AAD V2 so you need to use the Microsoft Authentication Libarary (MSAL) rather than the older ADAL for v1.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries